# How would a moment generating function change if all the random variables are increased by a value

Tags: mean, moments, moment-generating-function

Suppose you have some moment generating function $M_x(t)$
Now all the random variables x are increased by a arbitrary value b. What is the new moment generating value?

I tried solving this by moving back from the MGF to the probability distribution, but this proved impossible. Could somebody give me a nudge in the right direction? I'm looking for a 'proven' method instead of using intuition.
Thanks!

Edit:

Is this correct?

Declare a new variable $y = x + b$, so $x = y - b$

$E(e^{tx}) = E(e^{ty-tb}) = E(e^{ty})E(e^{-tb}) = M_y(t)E(e^{-tb}) =M_y(t)e^{-tb}$

Comment: Can you clarify? You use $x$ as argument to the mgf $M(x)$ and then name it `all the random variables x`, but the argument to the mgf **is not** the random variable!

Comment: Yes I get that. Let me rephrase it: I have some random variable x and the moment generating function of x is M(t)

Comment: Dear @Tijmen , please, update your question.

Comment: I already did update the question

Comment: Yes, that is correct! Now you can answer your own question, formally, so it does not linger as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a new variable $y = x + b$, so $x = y - b$

$E(e^{tx}) = E(e^{ty-tb}) = E(e^{ty})E(e^{-tb}) = M_y(t)E(e^{-tb}) =M_y(t)e^{-tb}$